# How do i make my Chatbot Message have some seconds of delay response in dialog flow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm creating a chatbot for a Facebook page to solve people's questions and I wanted to make the bot messages 1 or 2 seconds of delay between each of the bot's replies. Could someone tell me how to do it in dialog flow? I couldn't find any answer around my research so hopefully someone could help me.

Comment: How are you currently sending the replies, and what have you tried so far? It is difficult to help without seeing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible if you're using Dialogflow's built-in [rich messages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages). It also wouldn't be possible using only [webhook fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook) and the [Dialogflow Facebook integration](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/facebook), as you can only deliver a full set of messages as a reply at one time, and can't specify how they are delivered.

The only way to achieve that level of control would be to build the bot yourself (perhaps using an existing Messenger bot framework), and make calls from that code to Dialogflow to handle natural language understanding.